# Adding global font size styling to Axlsx sheet

Tags: excel, axlsx

I would like to set the sheet-wide default font size set to 8pt, instead of the default 11pt. Is there a way to set a global style using the [Axlsx](https://github.com/randym/axlsx) gem (implemented with [Axlsx-Rails](https://github.com/caxlsx/axlsx_rails))?

I've looked at the [axlsx_styler](https://github.com/axlsx-styler-gem/axlsx_styler) gem, which looks like it solves a few other styling limitations that are present in Axlsx out-the-box, however, it still doesn't seem to cater for global styles.

I realize of course that an option would be to use Axlsx's `style_name = wb.styles.add_style(...)` to set up a style and call it on every single row the sheet generates, but give there are other once-off styles that also need drizzling around the sheet, that doesn't seem like a great solution.

Are there any other ideas on how to achieve the setting of global styles on an Axlsx sheet?